# How do i display a ListView with a header below another ListView all in Tab1 of TabHost?

Tags: android, listview, android-tabhost

I'm trying to put a ListView below another ListView in the first tab using tabhost.

The reason i want it like this is because i want to divide a list of trading cards by type so i guess creating sections or whatever.

Here is my .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/banlistdate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="Banlist Date: March, 2013"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/banlistdate" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/fLV1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="#FF8B53"
                        tools:listheader="@layout/banlist_header_effectmonsters" >
                    </ListView>

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/fLV2"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="#a086b7"
                        tools:listheader="@layout/banlist_header_fusionmonsters" >
                    </ListView>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/flv3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >
                    </ListView>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/listView1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >
                    </ListView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my the main java file to start the tabs and setup the ListViews:

```
package cybertech.productions.yugiohlibrary;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Banlist extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TabHost th;

    Initializers initialMngr;

    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
    ListView forbiddenEMListView, forbiddenFListView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.banlist);
        th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        th.setup();
        TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        specs.setIndicator("Forbidden");
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        specs.setIndicator("Semi-Limited");
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        specs.setIndicator("Limited");
        th.addTab(specs);

        th.setCurrentTab(0);

        // #BEGIN: Tab 1 ListViews
        //Setup the "forbidden" ListView(s);

        // ListView 1: Effect Monsters
        forbiddenEMListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fLV1);
        ArrayList<String> forbiddenEMList = new ArrayList<String>();
        forbiddenEMList.addAll(Arrays.asList(initialMngr.forbiddenEM));
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, forbiddenEMList);
        View effectMon_header = View.inflate(this, R.layout.banlist_header_effectmonsters, null);
        forbiddenEMListView.addHeaderView(effectMon_header);
        forbiddenEMListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // ListView 2: Fusion Monsters
        forbiddenFListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fLV2);
        ArrayList<String> forbiddenFList = new ArrayList<String>();
        forbiddenFList.addAll(Arrays.asList(initialMngr.forbiddenF));
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, forbiddenFList);
        View fusion_header = View.inflate(this, R.layout.banlist_header_fusionmonsters, null);
        forbiddenFListView.addHeaderView(fusion_header);
        forbiddenFListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        // #END: Tab 1 ListViews
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). Use the group views to label the different categories or sections. Since you are using Arrays to back your lists, [SimpleExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleExpandableListAdapter.html) should fit the bill nicely.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try it out later on today and will let you know how it works.